# strptime, format and saving the milliseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

My gps, via gpsd, spits back a time in the format

`time_string = '1582-10-04T12:34:56.000Z'`

I can turn this string into a timezone aware `datetime` object
with

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
timeformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'  # ISO8601
datetime.strptime(time_string, timeformat).replace(tzinfo=(timezone(timedelta(0))))
```

...which is cool.  I can than manipulate the object, add, subtract, change timezones, calculate a time delta inclusive of a time zone change, etc..

The problem is occasionally some aspect of the application will return a time string with milliseconds attached.

`time_string = '1582-10-04T12:34:56.123Z'`

...and all hell breaks loose.

`.strip('Z')` doesn't do it.

`timeformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` <--without `.000` or `.000Z`
does not work either as neither `b.strip('.000Z')` or permutations thereof.

I can't seem to find an elegant way to save the millisecond(s), if, and when, they occur, and parse the string into a time zone aware datetime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about replacing the `000` by `%f`?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
time_string = '1582-10-04T12:34:56.123Z'
timeformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
datetime.strptime(time_string, timeformat).replace(tzinfo=(timezone(timedelta(0))))
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(1582, 10, 4, 12, 34, 56, 123000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

see [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for `%f` format.